# HTML: Div height needs to expand with content

Tags: css, html

I am a newbie to designing.

I think this question has already been asked several times so I am referring to one of them.

[make div's height expand with its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709442/make-divs-height-expand-with-its-content)

The solution posted on the above url ( adding "clear:both" after the main div closes) works great for me. But on one particular page, I have 3 divs left,middle and right where the content in middle div stretches up quite a bit, the other two divs do not stretch down.

I suspect its due to addition of the third div. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sorry to bother you all. I just found the mistake.
There was a typo in my code. the HTML was not correct. The middle div was closed with a  Hence the issue.

I appreciate the quick reply and support @True North Creative.

M

Comment: mark id as answered pls.