# Increasing height of a div while dynamically loading content (it's height is 100%)

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

I have a div(InnerDiv) which contains a grid with paging enabled...
After some user actions , data inside that grid will load and we will have a big grid!
The problem is when grid's data loads , overflow the div's bottom portion(InnerDiv) and some of those data get's displayed out of the div.

my css of body and html like below :

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0; /* get rid of default spacing on the edges */
    padding: 0; /* get rid of default spacing on the edges */
    border: 0; /* get rid of that 2px window border in Internet Explorer 6 */
    height: 100%; /* fill the height of the browser */
    border:3px solid red;
}
```

i need 100% height of body when page loads...

OuterDiv inside body like below :

```
div#OuterDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*height: auto;*/
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border:5px solid green;
}
```

InnerDiv Inside OuterDiv Is Like Below :

```
div#InnerDiv
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: transparent url('../Images/Blue.png') repeat scroll left top;
}
```

Content Inside InnerDiv Like Below :

```
#Content
{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    background: transparent url('../Images/Red.png') repeat scroll left top;
    width: 550px;
    height: 1080px; /*>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> plz see this line*/
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 7px;
    border: 10px ridge #ce004e;
    color: black;
}
```

that grid(Content) is inside InnerDiv...

**EDIT 1**
the below example can show my situation :
[Here's an example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kNJnJ/)

`we can not remove position:absolute of OuterDiv , by doing that height:auto or height:100% on it does not work at page start -> outerDiv should be 100% because Of InnerDiv Background and remember InnerDiv height is not 1080px at start -> it is only 200px at page load and dynamically it will change to 1080px!`

i want to force yellow area (InnerDiv) to fill entire Purple Area...
also InnerDiv Should Have 100% Height Because Of It's Background At Page Start...

i know this problem is about 100% height / but how can i fix that ?

**EDIT 2 :**
AT LAST HERE IS MY WEB SITE :
[MY WEB SITE](http://www.almasbms.com/)
plz change the height of red area with firebug - so by changing it to 1080px body and OuterDiv And InnerDiv Will grow.
but at page load i want body and OuterDiv And InnerDiv 100% height.
how can i do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: I tried but failed. :( Now I'm also interested in knowing answer to this question. +1.

Comment: Can you [upload the images](http://imgur.com/) you use as backgrounds (Red.png, Blue.png, back.png) and give us the links / use those links in your example. This will give us a clearer picture of what you want to achieve here (yes I read your update but it's a little vague to me)

Comment: i hate 100% height / always have problem with that...

Comment: just a moment - i am publishing my web site...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BsR9y.jpg | http://i.imgur.com/avej9.png | http://i.imgur.com/at996.png

Comment: A Nice Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709442/make-divs-height-expand-with-its-content/24226113#24226113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could gather from your explanation and styles you basically want this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/zXSXx/

If this is correct I will also explain what is happening to each div. Else please tell me what div is behaving not as you would like and why.

By the way if possible use absolute paths (whole links) to images. Seeing how they need to fit together will help us all to find something that works for you.

Comment: Exactly what part doesn't comply with what you have in mind? This is really difficult to do... I really think images might clear this right up... (I believe you're trying to do too much with absolute positioning)

Comment: thanks for comment - where is the other answer(vanished)? / plz see my highlight area in my Q.at page load i need OuterDiv 100% height because of InnerDiv background -> when we fix that the overflow appears after filling Content -> When We want to fix this one we lose 100% height(body-OuterDiv-And At Last InnerDiv) at page load. realy confused!

Comment: I a adapted my example ([jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/zXSXx/)) to use your images... Now when `Content` doesn't contain a lot its background will not fully expand, is this the problem? Do you want the red background to fill the 100% height too?...

Comment: Ok I think I understand the problem now, you want the `Content` div to have a height with 100% height so that the red background stretches down to the bottom, however this is not possible together due to extra spacing for the `Content` div (top and right) since this effectively makes the div longer than 100% of the window making it scroll even when theres no content in there. You want the min-height of #content to be 100% - 10px; + make the parents wrap arround this div.

Comment: thanks for comments - i test your fiddle and that is what i want - but in you fiddle there is no body area / besides overflow:auto in OuterDiv in my project causes an extra scroll bar that in jsfiddle we can not see that!

Comment: @MoonLight if what I have is what you want + you are using my styles then that shouldn't be happening.. can you update your own fiddle with the html, css you use in your project now after the changes?... It is possible you're missing something.

Comment: would you plz see my Q(EDIT 2) again...my web site!

Answer (score 2):

You need less constraints on `#OuterDiv`.  By specifying top, bottom, left, and right, you're locking the edges of #OuterDiv to the edges of `body`; and your body rule locks body to the same size as the viewport.

Try changing your `div#OuterDiv` rule like this:

```
div#OuterDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 5px solid green;
}
```

[Here's an example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/4eQMk/)

Comment: thanks for answer / but my InnerDiv(plz see my jsFiddle) Has A background-image and it should be 100% when page loads - also what about body in your jsfiddle (how can i force it to fill entire text?)

Comment: ok. I've updated your jsFiddle ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/kNJnJ/11/)).  The yellow box will start at `height:200px`, and when you click "Click to Grow", it will grow to 1080px. This demonstrates both states.  Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Lee: I also get the same result. But I think OP requires that yellow box should have minimum 100% height then grow as per inner Div `#content` grows in height. Any way lets see what OP has to say on your fiddle.

Comment: Yes , You Are Right - minimum height of InnerDiv should be 100% - because it has the middle background...i test Lee fiddle , but it has n't 100% at page load (but grows is ok in that)