# Do something when screen resolution changes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, height, screen-resolution

I want to set height of a div as height of window when page loads...

So I used the below code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var x = screen.availWidth;
            var y1 = screen.availHeight;
            var y2 = screen.Height;
            var w = $(window).height();
            var d = $(document).height();
            alert('availHeight : ' + y1);
            alert('Height : ' + y2);
            alert('window : ' + w);
            alert('document : ' + d);
            $('#OuterDiv').css({ 'height': w });
            //alert($('#OuterDiv').css('height'));
        });   //End Of $(document).reedy
```

Problem #1:

When screen resolution changes that div still have previous height.
How can I fix that ?

Problem #2:

I want height=100% for that div and because of some css problems I used jQuery.
But when page is loading (during page load) that div's height is the height of it's content and after that jQuery worked, that div gets window's height.

I think this is not nice during page load.
How can I fix this issue?

`height:100%` does not work for that div:

Here is the reason -> [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579294/increasing-height-of-a-div-while-dynamically-loading-content-its-height-is-100)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't just use CSS? If you set the width and height of your body to 100% and position your div absolutely, you should achieve the same effect.

Here's the jQuery event you're looking for, which sets #box to the width and height of the window

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var resizeBox = function() {
        $('#jq').css({width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height()});
    };
    resizeBox();
    $(window).resize(resizeBox);
});
```

Here's an example at http://jsfiddle.net/JxWm9/4/ which includes a CSS box for comparison. Note the JS version lags because it's based on the resize event, while the CSS resize is native to the browser itself.

Comment: @rooney thank you guys for answers / but i need something more faster than document.ready (Q #2) / what can i do about that issue?

Answer (score 5):

You can capture the resize event like so:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    alert($(window).width());
    alert($(window).height());
});
```

If you want to resize straight away, take the script out of the ready event, and put it inline, directly below your `div` (and maybe call it again on ready as well)

E.g.

```
<div class="myDiv">Content</div>
<script>$('#myDiv').height($(window).height());</script>
```