# Dynamic content height

Tags: html, css, dynamic, height

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [make div's height expand with its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709442/make-divs-height-expand-with-its-content)

On [my website](http://www.storylinedesign.be/sites/modu/ploegen/) you can see that I fixed the footer of the page at the bottom. It needs to be visible at all times because of our sponsors, that's why I fixed it.

Now the problem is that a part of the content is hidden behind the footer. I was able to fix this by adding a large height to the .container_12 div in css like this:

`.container_12 {
      height: 1500px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 960px;
    }`

But that's not a proper solution: for pages with only a little content it's way too high and are able to scroll all the way down leaving the content area all black; and when pages would grow in the future the height of 1500px could become insufficient.

Anyway, I just want it to fit, but don't know how to do it.

I hope anyone is able to help me!

Cheers guys

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709442/make-divs-height-expand-with-its-content

Comment: what have you done to your html/css! too many overflow: hidden; and position: fixed;. but for fast way do as @Burntime suggested.

Comment: thanks for the comment! where can I delete overflow hidden and position fixed?

Answer (score 1):

the fastest way I see is to add `margin-bottom: 360px;` to `.container_12`

Comment: it worked, but why so much? the footer is not that high at all, but yet I need to put around 400px to make it work, like you said..

Comment: I think its related to `body: { height: 100% }` there are a lot of redundant styles. Would take some time to find the exact reason.