# Onclick of anchor tag I am showing Customer Testimonials DIV but the height is not expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am displaying customer testimonials in a horizontal scroll using flexslider. They are displayed when you click on view all testimonials link as shown below in JSFiddle

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2c7pzqx0/)</kbd>**

**JQuery**

```
$('#see-all').click(function () {
   $(".cust-reviews-show").slideToggle();
});
$('.cd-testimonials-wrapper').flexslider({
    selector: ".cd-testimonials > li",
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    slideshow: false,
    smoothHeight: true,
    start: function () {
        $('.cd-testimonials').children('li').css({
            'opacity': 1,
            'position': 'relative'
     });
    }
});
```

You will notice that when the link is clicked the testimonial container gets displayed but the height is getting not expanding. I am pretty sure I am missing like style height or something.

Any advice is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I tried my best to post the link to JSFiddle but it kept telling me to include in the code block. there was no means I was trying to abuse anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

[make div's height expand with its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709442/make-divs-height-expand-with-its-content)

Setting height=auto in the CSS for your DIV might do the trick. Read the article theres an interesting technique to expand divs aitomaticaly explained there. Hope it helps.