# change div height as the content grows automatically

Tags: css, wordpress, height

I am customizing a wordpress theme and in a popup I am displaying a contact form when you click `Book a Valuation` menu item [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/91ozfa), you can see that content is overflowing(i do not want to add scrollbar). I have followed all the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709442/make-divs-height-expand-with-its-content) but nothing helped me to solve the problem. Website [link](http://www.informatixtech.com/joulesestateagents.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `height: auto;` in your CSS.

Comment: using height auto makes the background transparent,

Comment: I still see `!important`. Is that for a reason? Probably because you also set `height` inline, but still in px.

Comment: oh just removed that but you can see now that it has increased the height too much. http://prntscr.com/91pjl7

Comment: As you can see in the browser developer tools, the `height` is set in line, which causes it to be 400px high.

Comment: removed that but now background is transparent again

Comment: It's because of the positioning. You can see the difference when you disable the `bottom` style for example.

Comment: oh amazing, but why is that? can you please explain.