# Making parent element expand to contain a relatively positioned child?

Tags: html, css

Is there an easy way (without manually setting any heights) to make sure a parent element always wraps/contains a child, even if the child has been relatively positioned?

```html
<div style="background-color: red;">
  <div style="background-color: pink; position: relative; top: 20px">
    one.
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  two.
</div>
```

In the example above the "one." div flows out of its parent and overlaps/hides the "two." div, but my desired effect is to have the parent div contain the whole of the child and the "two." element flowing underneath.

Comment: refer this: duplicate: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709442/make-divs-height-expand-with-its-content?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa>

Comment: that's about floats, this isn't, not a duplicate. This was a silly question though, mehulmpt answered it perfectly, been out of web stuff for far too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`top` is used to position element so that it has **no effect** on the surrounding elements. Use `margin-top` if you want to affect the parent as well, otherwise `top` doesn't affect the other elements.

```html
<div style="background-color: red; display: flex;">
  <div style="background-color: pink; position: relative; margin-top: 20px">
    one.
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  two.
</div>
```

Comment: Doh! Now I feel stupid, hadn't done web stuff for a long time. Thanks!